# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'user'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вылетает ошибка при подключении базе данных через hibernate. Успешно коннектится, но, когда пытается изменить базу данных --> выкидывает эту ошибку. Пароль не менял, стандартный 1234. 
Гуглил про забытый пароль, но ведь пароль один и тот же везде использую. В чём проблема и как можно изменить?

Comment: По ошибке видно, что ругается на отсутствие диалекта. Укажите диалект базы данных.

Comment: Замените изображение на текст ошибки и покажите конфигурацию и код, относящиеся к вопросу.

Comment: Я уже понял, в чём была ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Проблема была в том, что в конфигурационном файле hibernate был указан 
root - root, вместо root - 1234. Также я понял, что можно создать нового пользователя в mysql, дать ему максимум прав и использовать его.